# Action script for login form not working

Tags: php, html

having problems understanding why my script to login will not work, so its a simple login script that checks the users and fields as expected yet when it does the logic it does not seem to be loggin in the users :S

action script:

```
    <?php

        if ( $SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] == 'POST' )

        {

        require ( 'connect_db.php' );

        require ( 'login_tools.php' );

        list ( $check , $data ) =

            validate ( $dbc , $_POST[ 'email' ] , $_POST [ 'pass' ] ) ;

        if ( $check )

        {
            session_start() ;

            $_SESSION[ 'user_id' ] = $data [ 'user_id' ] ;
            $_SESSION[ 'first_name' ] = $data  [ 'first_name' ] ;
            $_SESSION[ 'last_name' ] = $data  [ 'last_name' ] ;

            load ('home.php');

        }

        else { $errors = $data ; }

        mysqli_close( $dbc );


        }


?>
```

An action script to process the login:

```
<?php

function load( $page = 'login.php')

    {

    $url = 'http://' . $SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . 
                        dirname( $_SERVER ['PHP_SELF'] );

    $url = rtrim( $url , '/\\' );
    $url = '/' . $page ;

    header ( "location: $url" );
    exit();     

    }

function validate( $dbc , $email = ',$pwd = ')


    {

    $errors = array();

    if (empty($email))

    { $errors[] = 'Enter your email address.' ; }

    else

    { $e = mysqli_real_escape_string( $dbc , trim( $email ) ) ; }

    if (empty($pwd))

    { $errors[] = 'Enter your password.' ; }

    else

    { $e = mysqli_real_escape_string( $dbc , trim( $pwd ) ) ; } 

    if ( empty( $errors ) )

    {

    $q = "SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE enail = '$e' AND pass = SHA1( '$p' )";

    $r = mysqli_query ( $dbc , $q ) ;

    if ( mysqli_num_rows( $r ) == 1 )

    {

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $r , MYSQLI_ASSOC );
    return array (true , $row );

    }

    else

    {

    $errors[] = 'Email address and password not found.' ;

    }

    return array( false , $errors) ; }

    }
?>
```

And it will land here...

```
<?php

session_start();

    if ( !isset( $_SESSION[ 'user_id' ] ) )

    {

        require ( 'login_tools.php' ) ;
        load() ;

    }

    $page_title = 'Home' ;


    echo'<p>
    <a href="goodbye.php">logout</a>
    </p> ';

?>
```

The login script tried to execute login_action.php but dosnt move from there...I have no syntax errors though?

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled $_SERVER variable - there is not such thing like $SERVER

## EDIT

### login_tools.php

```
function validate($dbc, $email = ',$pwd = ')
```

should be:

```
function validate($dbc, $email = '' , $pwd = '')
```

next:

```
$e = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($pwd));
```

should be:

```
$p = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($pwd));
```

and return statement move after if statement:

```
if (empty($errors)) {
    ...
}

return array(false, $errors);
```

I hope that you're playing around with PHP or something, beacuse this is really bad code. But you know that, right?

Comment: Thanks man this should work I found a typo too which wasnt picked up!

Comment: No errors at all! This is why it is so confusing...I have written a new script but now im getting an error stating that the email or password is wrong - it isnt though

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found a new script to see if I can see if it its a problem with the database, table or the script - Heres the new script:

Login.php

```
<h1>Login</h1>

<form action="login_action.php" method="POST">

<p>

Email Address: <input type="text" name="email" />

</p><p>

Password: <input type="password" name="pass" />

</p><p>

<input type="submit" value="login"  />

</p>

</form>
```

checklogin.php

```
<?php

include ('connect_db.php');


$myemail=$_POST['email'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myemail = stripslashes($myemail);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myemail = mysql_real_escape_string($myemail);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT user_id, email, first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE email='$myemail' and pass='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("email");
session_register("mypassword");
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong email or Password";
}
```

?>

login_success.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(email)){
header("location:login.php");
}
?>

<html>
<body>
Login Successful
</body>
</html>
```

The error I get now is the email or password is wrong? I know that it isnt...

Comment: Print SQL query, copy it and past in MySQL client to execute directly (without php), is it working?

Comment: BTW are you aware of that you shouldn't use mysql_* functions?