# Should this function be working? - new to php

Tags: php

I have function within my login script that is causing me some problems. I believe this is the issue.

```
function load( $page = 'login.php')

    {

    $url = 'http://' . $SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . 
                        dirname( $_SERVER ['PHP_SELF'] );

    $url = rtrim( $url , '/\\' );
    $url = '/' . $page ;

    header ( "location: $url" );
    exit();     

    }
```

My users are in the db and can register fine - when using my login form I have a login form a script to check they have entered the info and also another one to validate the users. The problem being that when I/They attempt to login the action script or the logic dosnt move on it sits on that blank page...

Answer (score 1):

Thats the white page of death :) There is an error, but it doesnt get shown. You can try adding this to the top:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
```

That should give you the error on line 5 in this code, the `$SERVER` needs to be `$_SERVER`

---

To improve your code, this is valid too:

```
header('Location: /');
```

Relative url's. That piece of code will go to home, you can just to to your `$page` directly:

```
header('Location: /'.$page);
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Im still getting the white screen of death though :( any chance you are able to look at my script to see why?

Comment: Why are you bitwise `OR`'ing `E_ALL` with `E_WARNING` seeing as `E_ALL` already has `E_WARNING` included? The only error constant missing is `E_STRICT`.

Comment: check for error_log file in your FTP root folder or where this php file is located.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Im not getting any errors show....the page moves from login.php and white screens on login_action.php and goes no further

Answer (score 0):

```
function load($page = "login.php") {
   header(sprintf("Location: http://%s/%s/%s", $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"], trim(dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]), "/"), $page));
   exit();
}
```

Comment: Could you expand on where thi should be placed and what the difference is at all?

Comment: can u try replacing your load function with this one and see if it moves or not... if it still doesnt, there is a good chance the problem isn't here and you might then have to go thru other clauses of login system.

Comment: yes there was. I missed  ")" in the end. I am not using an IDE and doing some other work too sorry I missed that. Updated my answer though

Comment: still stuck at the same point - are you able to take a look at my script here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440840/action-script-for-login-form-not-working